# Paper on unit disk graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-geometry

I was wondering if anybody knows of a 'link' to the paper by Marathe 1995 et al on analysis of the greedy algorithm for finding a Max independent set in Unit Disk Graphs?

Comment: *Simple heuristics for unit disk graph* is here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230250205/abstract but I think it is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9409226v1

confusingly, arXiv lists this article with a different title, but it's the paper published as

M.V. Marathe, H. Breu, H.B. Hunt, S.S. Ravi, and D.J. Rosenkrantz, *Simple heuristics for unit disk graphs.* Networks, **25**, 59-68 (1995).